# arcpy.CopyFeatures_management error due to bad naming convention

Tags: python, arcpy

I have a script that downloads a zip file and extracts the shapefile each day. This works fine, but the shapefile is always in the format "polygons.yyyymmdd.shp"

I keep getting errors when trying to copy this file to a geodatabase. I am guessing because there is a period in the shapefile name (no idea why they use this kind of naming structure).

The error is "RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool"

```
shpList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
print shpList
>>>[u'polygons.20150316.shp']

polyFc = "C:\\data\\work.gdb\\" + "polyFc"
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(shpList, polyFc)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# I renamed using the following:
for filename in os.listdir("."):
    print filename
    if filename.startswith("polygons"):
        os.rename(filename, "a" + filename[9:])

# To import the shapefile into my geodb I converted the list to string first
shp = '\n'.join(shpList)
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(shp, outWorkspace, "polyToday")
```

Answer (score 2):

Geoprocessing tools will object to shapefiles (and dbase files) with an extra period in their name. Will need to rename the files prior to using them with CopyFeatures and other tools.

```
folder, shp_name = os.path.split(shp)
name = os.path.splitext(shp_name)[0]

for file_name in os.listdir(folder):
    if file_name.startswith(name):
        os.rename(os.path.join(folder, file_name),
                  os.path.join(folder, file_name.replace('.', '_', 1)))
```

Comment: Thanks. Will this work with a list? shpList is a list. Also what is the shp variable?

Comment: The above is just for a single shapefile, you'd have to add another level of indentation to iterate through a list. `for shp in shpList`